# Error while running webpack-dev-server with grunt

Tags: reactjs, webpack, gruntjs, webpack-dev-server, react-hot-loader

I am currently working on a sails-react project. I wish to use `webpack-dev-server` with `react-hot-load` for fast development. To do so I added the modules and created the config files. Just using the webpack-dev-server works fine, so I guess the webpack configurations are all correct. (If this helps I can post the configuration as well)

Now I wanted to start the `webpack-dev-server` using `grunt`. I created this `webpack.js` grunt configuration file and added `webpack-dev-server:start` to the `default` task.

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = function(grunt) {
  //const webpack = require('webpack');
  const webpackConfig = require('../../webpack.config');
  const webpackConfigProduction = require('../../webpack.production.config');

  grunt.config.set('webpack', {
    options: webpackConfigProduction,
    build: {}
  });

  grunt.config.set('webpack-dev-server', {
    options: {
      webpack: webpackConfig,
      host: 'localhost',
      port: 8080,
      historyApiFallback: true,
      hot: true,
      contentBase: path.join(__dirname, "../../app"),
      publicPath: '/assets/',
    },
    start: {}
  });

  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-webpack');
};
```

The grunt task starts the webpack-dev-server as expected.

First difference I noticed is the console output of dev-server prints `Project is running at http://localhost/` instead of expected `Project is running at http://localhost:8080/`, so maybe the port was not correctly initialized?

Then the error: Starting the browser at `http://localhost:8080/` loads the correct index.html, but an error occurs.

`Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list`

Caused by this line of code:

```
if (module.hot) module.hot.accept('./components/App.jsx', () => {
    const NewApp = require('./components/App.jsx').default;
    render(NewApp);
});
```

Because somehow webpack (only using grunt, just starting webpack-dev-server from command line works) transforms this to:

```
if (true) module.hot.accept("./app/components/App.jsx""./app/components/App.jsx", 
function () {
  var NewApp = __webpack_require__("./app/components/App.jsx").default;
  render(NewApp);
});
```

I have no idea why "./app/components/App.jsx" is duplicated when using grunt-webpack.